# Extract Volume Name from ISO using Command?

Tags: ubuntu, iso-image, extract

I'm building a bootable CD/DVD using Ubuntu's `genisoimage`. The new image is based on the old image downloaded from Ubuntu's website. (The only change made was `BOOTx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`).

How do I extract the old ISO's volume name from the command line? I want to pass it to `genisoimage` for the new ISO.

Answer (score 2):

Try `file -s`:

```
  $ file -s kubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso 
  kubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso: # ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Kubuntu 13.10 amd64             ' (bootable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up using to extract the volume name. I was using it in a shell script:

```
SOURCE_ISO=...
VOLUME_LINE=`isoinfo -d -i "$SOURCE_ISO" | grep -i "Volume id:"`
VOLUME_NAME=${VOLUME_LINE:11}
echo "Volume name: $VOLUME_NAME"
```